# how to set a "breakpoint" to stack a row using zurb foundation grid

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation

Lets say I have a row with two elements on 12 column grid:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">part 1</div>
    <div class="nine columns">part 2</div>
</div>
```

Normally they are displayed side by side. like:

```
part1      part2
```

But in case the screen is smaller than XXX it would be
displayed as if there were 2 rows...

```
part1
part2
```

Can zurb foundation do that? or any other framework?

**Edit:** I would like to specify the value of the breakpoint (XXX) myself.
Not only relying on the default behaviour.

Comment: This is the default behavior of foundation. I don't understand the question. http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/grid.php

Comment: See also: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.php

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to change the breakpoint, then you need to modify the breakpoints outlined here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.php

```
/* Medium screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1279px) and (min-width: 768px) { ... }

/* Small screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { ... }
```